# Python 3 Tkinter notebook tabid. How to return the text of all tabs instead of the number ids?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hey guys I've been learning about Tkinter and making some GUI apps. I'm experimenting with the notebook widget and I'm stuck at one spot. I was wondering if there is a way to use a for loop for all of the current tabs and return the text names of all the tabs instead of the number id. I would like to use it to keep track of the frames. I have searched around and found out how to show tab text for the current tab but I need all the tabs. I haven't been able to find anything specifically for that. Let me know if you have an idea. Thanks.

[EDIT] Code snippet

```html
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter import ttk


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
        self.second_window()
        self.pm_tabs = []

    def init_window(self):# Builds the UI for the main window

        self.n = ttk.Notebook(root)

        self.get_tabs_button = Button(self.textboxframe,
                                      width=20,
                                      text='Get Tab Names',
                                      command=lambda:self.get_tab_names())
        self.get_tabs_button.grid(row = 0,
                                  column= 1,
                                  padx=(5,5),
                                  pady=(5,150),
                                  sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.n.add(self.textboxframe, text='Chat')
        self.n.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

    def second_window(self):# UI for second window

        self.get_tabs_button = Button(self.textboxframe,
                                      width=20,
                                      text='Get Tab Names',
                                      command=lambda:self.get_tab_names())
        self.get_tabs_button.grid(row = 0,
                                  column= 1,
                                  padx=(5,5),
                                  pady=(5,150),
                                  sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.n.add(self.textboxframe, text='Second')

    def get_tab_names(self): # get the names of the tabs. Hoping to get the text names of the tab.
        for tabs in self.n.tabs():
            print(tabs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. This question could be improved if you give us an example of what you've already tried, or include information on what exactly you found.

Comment: The code its a little long to post here. Basically I'm making a little chat client that uses tabs for private messages. When a private message comes I look for the name of the person who sent it, and generate a tab with a 2 text boxes, one for input and one for displaying messages sent and received. What I would like to do is, when a message comes in, look at the username and have it go through a for loop and if there is a tab with the text of the tab being that name, post the incoming text there. I don't know if that makes sense. I can try to make a little sample code.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've added a small code snippet. I hope that helps.

Comment: Edit isn't good enough. Please create a minimal and _complete_ example illustrating this issue—something folks could actually run.

Comment: I would have to post the entire code to show my problem. Its far too long to post here.  Also,  to test the code one would need their own private irc to connect and test. I guess I'll just close the post.

Comment: You don't have to post the entire code (nor do we need/want to see it). For something minimal, just create a little tkinter app that has a `ttk.Notebook` with several panels and a button to display or print their names.

Comment: I'll give it a try and see if I can put something together.

Comment: Ok, I've added some working code everyone can use.

Comment: That is way too much code. You can illustrate the problem with about a dozen lines of code. For the purposes of this question it doesn't matter what is in each tab, so they can be left blank.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow and python in general. Thanks for the tips. I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the official documentation, the [tab](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Notebook.tab) method of the notebook can be used to return information about a tab, such as the text on the tab.

Thus, you can get a list of the text for all of the tabs with something like this:

```
notebook = ttk.Notebook(...)
...
tab_names = [notebook.tab(i, option="text") for i in notebook.tabs()]
```

If you're new to list comprehensions, the above is the same as this:

```
tab_names = []
for i in notebook.tabs():
    tab_names.append(notebook.tab(i, "text"))
```